# How to adjust space between broken lines in vertex labels?

Tags: r, igraph

I know that in base R I can use `par(lheight = ...)` to adjust the space between two lines that are broken by `\n`, e.g. in axis labels. I was wondering how to adjust the space between lines in multi-line vertex labels in `igraph`. I could not find an answer here on Stack Overflow, I hope I have not overseen anything obvious. Or is there any other option to break lines than using `\n` in igraph that allows to adjust the space?

```
library(igraph)
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob\nSurname", "Cecil\nSurname", "Cecil\nSurname", "David\nSurname",
                               "David\nSurname", "Esmeralda\nSurname"),
                        to=c("Alice\nSurname", "Bob\nSurname", "Alice\nSurname", "Alice\nSurname", "Bob\nSurname", "Alice\nSurname"))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=FALSE)
plot(g)
# this does not change the space between first name and surname...
par(lheight = .1)
plot(g)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works perfectly. Maybe you tried to see too small difference? [Here](https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/blob/dev/R/plot.R) you see that igraph plotting is built on top of basic R graphics. Labels are plotted by calling `text()` (near line 394) which takes the `lheight` parameter either from `par` or as argument in `...` (here not used). Therefore setting `par(lheight = x)` must determine the label line height. Testing with your graph:

```
png('graph_lheight1.png')
    par(lheight = 1)
    plot(g)
dev.off()
```

[image: Line height = 1]

```
png('graph_lheight2.png')
    par(lheight = 2)
    plot(g)
dev.off()
```

[image: Line height = 2]

Comment: mh, strange, in my plots this did not work. maybe i have to check some additional settings. in any case you could confirm that this works and i know where NOT to look for the error ;-).

Comment: what is your graphic device?

Comment: you got me, I was just using the RStudio device and forgot that it does usually not perform very well. it seems i had turned off my brains, usually I use `pdf` and `svg` via `svglight`. seems like everything works now...to make the space between lines "disappear" a value of `lheight = .5` seems to work.